# Рендер футера и навбара по любому пути, а основная часть вариантивна react (SPA)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

У меня навбар и футер должны быть на каждой странице. Я роутинг делал так

const store = createStore(reducer, composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunk)));

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <Navbar />
    <Provider store={store}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
          <Route path="/personal/desktop" component={Desktop} />
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>
    <Footer />
  </div>,

  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Но в этом случае, у меня почему-то при переходе по ссылке /personal/desktop снова подгружаются лого и т.п. из навбара и футера.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Достаточно просто обвернуть код в какой-то компонент или div

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
          <Link to="/">Admin</Link>
          <Navbar />
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
            <Route path="/personal/desktop" component={Desktop} />
          </Switch>
          <Footer />
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>
  </div>,

  document.getElementById("root")
);
```